# What does it mean, "It was either us or Arlington"?

Tags: bloodshot-2020

Bloodshot woke up from death, and talked with the Dr Emil:

> Dr Emil: Yes, your body was donated by the U.S. military.
>
> Bloodshot: My body?
>
> Dr Emil: **It was either us or Arlington**, I'm afraid.

What does it mean, "It was either us or Arlington"?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Arlington National Cemetery is the burial place for many of the US's war dead. From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arlington_National_Cemetery):

> Arlington National Cemetery is a United States military cemetery in Arlington County, Virginia, across the Potomac River from Washington, D.C., in whose 624 acres the dead of the nation's conflicts have been buried, beginning with the Civil War, as well as reinterred dead from earlier wars.

Without knowing anything about the film, presumably the doctor is saying that if the body hadn't been donated to them, it would have been buried.

Comment: You are correct, Sir. The protagonist is a Special Forces soldier who is killed in the line of duty and would be entitled to an army burial